# Python quickest way to combine 2 list of dictionaries into one list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
ldict1 = [{"id":1, "name":"apple", "colour": "", "type": ""}, 
          {"id":2, "name":"orange", "colour": "", "type":""}]
ldict2 = [{"id":1, "colour":"red", "type":"fruit"}, 
          {"id":2, "colour":"orange", "type":"fruit"}]
```

Above is an example of the 2 types of list of dictionaries I want to merge. The id is the same for both. The length of both is long. I could only think of nested for loops but that could take time. What could be the quickest way to merge the same.

Expected

```
ldict = [{"id":1, "name":"apple", "colour": "red", "type": "fruit"}, 
         {"id":2, "name":"orange", "colour": "orange", "type":"fruit"}]
```

Note that the two lists always have the same order of id. Also, I want to add the missing details of `ldict1` from `ldict2`. Those keys are always empty in `ldict1` which need to be filled by `ldict2`.

Comment: Do two lists have always same order of `id`?

Comment: @Chris Yes it is the same id

Comment: Does ldict2 always override the dicts in ldict1?

Comment: @user48956 Yes. I want to add the missing details of ldict1 from ldict2. Those keys are always empty in ldict1 which need to be filled by ldict2

Comment: Do you need a new list of new dicts or is it ok to modify the dicts in `ldict1` instead? That could be quicker.

Comment: @KellyBundy I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @enke  Fell free to do it instead. I'm too tired, especially for writing a benchmark on my phone that I'd want to do.

Comment: @KellyBundy Modifying the ldict1 would also be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try with:

```
out = [{**i, **j} for i,j in zip(ldict1, ldict2)]
```

or if you have Python>=3.9:

```
out = [i | j for i,j in zip(ldict1, ldict2)]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'apple', 'colour': 'red', 'type': 'fruit'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'orange', 'colour': 'orange', 'type': 'fruit'}]
```

Note that this works only if the `id`s match each pair of `i`-`j`. Also in the event that a key has values in both `i` and `j`, only the value from `j` is kept.

Also, (probably wouldn't be that different from a double loop but) if the `id`s don't match, we could use pandas module and use it's `fillna` method:

```
import pandas as pd
out = pd.DataFrame(ldict1).replace('', float('nan')).fillna(pd.DataFrame(ldict2)).to_dict('records')
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer meets the OP's need, here's one way to merge two dicts if we don't know which dict has to be updated:

```
# test data
ldict1 = [{"id":1, "name":"apple", "colour": "", "type": "fruit"}, 
          {"id":2, "name":"orange", "colour": "", "type":""}]
ldict2 = [{"id":1, "colour":"red", "type":""},  # type is missing here
          {"id":2, "colour":"orange", "type":"fruit"}]

[{k: i.get(k) or j.get(k) for k in {*i, *j}} for i, j in zip(ldict1, ldict2)]
```

Output:

```
[{'type': 'fruit', 'colour': 'red', 'id': 1, 'name': 'apple'},
 {'type': 'fruit', 'colour': 'orange', 'id': 2, 'name': 'orange'}]
```